# Magento 2, In checkout page shipping method is loading while changing the shipping address

Tags: shipping-methods, shipping-address, customer-address, onestepcheckout, magento2.4.5p1

Magento 2, On the custom checkout page, the shipping method is loading while I am changing the shipping address and getting the below error in the browser console.

js.storage.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
|     property 'form' -> object with constructor 'jQuery.fn.init'
|     property '0' -> object with constructor 'HTMLFormElement'
|     ...
|     property '$parents' -> object with constructor 'Array'
index 0 closes the circle
at JSON.stringify ()

On the above error message, it shows there should be an error in stringify, but I tried removing the $parent and form objects from the JSON, but those properties do not exist in the JSON.stringify. please help on it

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Any third party module for the checkout ?

Comment: No, I am creating a custom one-step checkout module, and the above error message triggers only when I have the configurable product with selected options in the checkout then whenever I change the address above error message in thrown, and the shipping method is loading.

Comment: And also above error throws only when the configurable product options are editable. when it is non-editable the error is not thrown